# How can I finish this proof of the existence of the empty set?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, set-theory, axioms

I am trying to prove the existence of the empty set for self-study:
$$\exists X\forall x(x\notin X)$$
I am trying to use the axiom schema of specification.
$$∀Y∃X∀x(x∈X⟺(x∈Y∧φ(x)))$$
I am confused on argument #2 of the proof.

Note the following abbreviations:
$x\neq X\iff\neg x=X$
$x\notin X\iff\neg x\in X$

1. $\forall Y\exists X\forall x(x\in X\iff (x\in Y\land \phi(x)))$
   axiom schema of specification
2. $\forall Y\exists X\forall x(x\in X\iff (x\in Y\land x\neq x))$
   second-order logic? 1
3. $\exists X\forall x(x\in X\iff (x\in Y\land x\neq x))$
   universal instantiation Y/Y 2
4. $\forall x(x\in X\iff (x\in Y\land x\neq x))$
   existential instantiation X/X 3
5. $x\in X\iff (x\in Y\land x\neq x)$
   universal instantiation x/x 4
6. $x\in X\implies (x\in Y\land x\neq x)$
   biconditional elimination 5
7. $(x\in X\implies x\in Y)\land(x\in X\implies x\neq x)$
   distributivity of implication over conjunction 6
8. $x\in X\implies x\neq x$
   simplification (to second conjunct) 7
9. $\forall x(x=x)$
   reflexivity of equality
10. $x=x$
    universal instantiation x/x 9
11. $\neg x\neq x$
    double negation introduction 10
12. $x\notin X$
    modus tollendo tollens 8,11
13. $\forall x(x\notin X)$
    universal generalization 12
14. $\exists X\forall x(x\notin X)$
    existential generalization 13

I don't know how to go from an axiom schema to one specific formula.

What rule of inference can I use to complete the proof?

Do I need to study second-order logic to handle this axiom schema?

Comment: If there are any problems with the rest of the proof, please tell me)). I am new to making proofs. Thank you guys.

Comment: First order logic is sufficient for this problem. What's so significant about #2? It just specifies that $\phi (x)$ means $x\neq x$ .

Comment: Is there a rule of inference that lets me "instantiate" the schema?

Comment: I don't get it how we invoke universal instantiation in a meaningful way here. The claim is that every $Y$ has some property ..but who ever said such $Y$ existed..? What are your assumptions?

Comment: The separation axiom is an *axiom schema*, a collection of countably many axioms, one axiom for every formula $\varphi(x)$.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, is the rest of the proof good?